# Magento Redirect URL?

Tags: php, magento

Hellow friemds i develop a magento website and i created page and i want to linked that page into navigation menu bar

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar
```

Comment: Can you add more info about your rewrite?

Comment: Change it from CMS Page to Static block, add new category, and under 'display settings' change display mode to 'static only' and choose proper CMS Block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting With Magento CE 1.7 there is an event that lets you add anything to the top menu.
The event is `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`. In the default theme, this is used to add categories in the menu. Check out the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems()`. You can do the same.
If you are working on versions before 1.7 just edit the file `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml` and add your link inside the `ul` element:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('', array('_direct'=>'page_identifier_here'))?>"><?php echo $this->__('Text here')?></a></li>
</ul>
```

or like this

```
<ul id="nav">
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('page_identifier_here')?>"><?php echo $this->__('Text here')?></a></li>
</ul>
```

The approach for version 1.6 works in 1.7 also but it's not that clean.